# How do I alphabetically sort my immutable array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How do I manage to alphabetically sort an immutable array in Swift? Here's the code:

```
let sports = [golf,rugby,football,basketball,soccer,cricket,baseball,softball,handball,volleyball,hockey,lacrosse,swimming,polo,water polo]
```

And will this newly sorted array be displayed in a table view alphabetically?

Comment: Is your array supposed to be an array of strings?

Comment: yes all strings @Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
let sports: [String] = {
    var temp = ["golf","rugby","football","basketball","soccer","cricket","baseball","softball","handball","volleyball","hockey","lacrosse","swimming","polo","water polo"]
    temp.sort(<)
    return temp
}()
```

This calls a closure to create the sorted array.  If in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you use `indexPath.row` to index into this array, your `TableView` will be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sports = ["golf","rugby","football","basketball","soccer","cricket","baseball","softball","handball","volleyball","hockey","lacrosse","swimming","polo","water polo"]

sports = sports.sorted {$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }

println(sports)
```

Cheers:)